# jquery fadeIn not working

Tags: jquery

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong:

style:

```
.warning{border: 1px solid #F0AAAA; background:#FFBABA; color: #C90000;}
```

markup:

```
 <p class="warning">A successful authorization already exists. 
                    Further authorizations are not allowed at this time.</p>
```

script:

```
 $().ready(function () {
     alert($(".warning").html());     // WORKS
     $(".warning").fadeIn(4000);      // DOESN'T WORK
 });
```

Comment: What are you expecting fadeIn() to do? If .warning is not visible, fadeIn will make it visible, but according to your CSS there is no reason to expect it to be hidden.

Comment: My scenario was that the warning div would show up anyway when the page was loaded. I just wanted to fade it in slow once the user landed on that page. So I didn't want to set display:none in the stylesheet. But as Nick suggested below .hide().fadeIn() was exactly what I needed for it to work in this scenario.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Unless the element is hidden, no fade will occur, you need something like this:

```
$(".warning").hide().fadeIn(4000);
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ubgHd/), also `$()` is deprecated in 1.4+, you should use `$(document)` or the shorter version, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".warning").hide().fadeIn(4000);
});
```

The alternative is to give the element a `display: none` initially *but* this breaks for JS-disabled users, or if JavaScript errors occur preventing the fade, so you may want to steer clear of this approach.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `elm.css('opacity', '0').fadeIn()` and `elm.css('opacity', '0').hide().fadeIn()` which don't display anything. The second fails because `hide` stores the original opacity value, so it was fading in to 0.

Answer (score 11):

add `display:none` to your css code.

```
.warning{border: 1px solid #F0AAAA; background:#FFBABA; color: #C90000;display:none}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I'm avoiding this solution because of the pitfalls pointed out in the above response.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to think you want some event to be managed for the fadin. see working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hPHPn/

Thus:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".warning").hide();// hide it initially
    $('#unhideit').click(function(){
        $(".warning").fadeIn(4000);                            });
});
```

for some simple markup:

```
<p class="warning">A successful authorization already exists  
    for this Quote ID. Further authorizations are not allowed at this time.</p> 
<input type="button" id="unhideit" value="clickme" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done the same thing in my application. At the top of my `html` document I have:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="advtemp3jquery.js"></script>
```

The part which says `src="advtemp3jquery.js` refers to my external `.js` file. I find it neater to keep the code in an external file.

The script does the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.header1,.header2').fadeIn('4000');
});
```