# I am trying to make a JQuery anination but it won't work

Tags: jquery

Ok so here is the code that I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img#full_image_actual").delay(1000).fadeIn(2000); 
});
```

It is also inside the script attribute used in HTML, I know for a fact that I have the correct ID tag but for some reason the animation just does't work. Do anyone see a problem with my code?

Comment: TIP: You could write the selector just like this: `$("#full_image_actual")`. It's not expected to have more than one element with the same ID.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Add your relevant HTML & CSS code. Also, reproducing the error in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be helpful.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery fadeIn not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398882/jquery-fadein-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("img#full_image_actual").hide().delay(1000).fadeIn(2000); 
});
```

You have to add hide before fadeIn effet because fadein effect will work if the element is hidden first.

Comment: This can be the answer.

Comment: Agree to @undefined, but an explanation with the code would be appreciated.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I have been added explanation for my answer.

Comment: I noticed that. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks dude, I can not believe that I missed this!